# Javascript function for painting connected walls in labyrinth?

Tags: javascript, function, svg

I have a problem for which made simplified code for express it. In few words I need to build code in Javascript for painting connected SVG lines. The simple example:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >

<line x1="50" y1="50" x2="200" y2="50" stroke="steelblue" stroke-width="20" onclick="fillWall(evt)" />
<line x1="100" y1="100" x2="400" y2="100" stroke="steelblue" stroke-width="20" onclick="fillWall(evt)" />
<line x1="300" y1="300" x2="200" y2="300" stroke="steelblue" stroke-width="20" onclick="fillWall(evt)" />
<line x1="100" y1="50" x2="100" y2="400" stroke="steelblue" stroke-width="20" onclick="fillWall(evt)" />
<line x1="300" y1="100" x2="300" y2="300" stroke="steelblue" stroke-width="20" onclick="fillWall(evt)" />
<line x1="200" y1="300" x2="200" y2="200" stroke="steelblue" stroke-width="20" onclick="fillWall(evt)" />

<script type="text/javascript"> 
<![CDATA[
function fillWall(evt) {
  var tgt=evt.target;
  tgt.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "firebrick");
}
]]>
</script>
</svg>
```

This is labyrinth of few walls when you click on some it changes color, so I need to do it with one click to paint all connected, no matter on which wall click is applied. In full sized scale there are almost thousand of these walls, and some are connected, some aren't. I tried to learn recursive functions, but easily exceeded stack size. 
Please help, I'll appreciate that a huge.

Comment: You want to color any overlapping lines. Is that correct?

Comment: @Amaan if you mean a lines which are across - no. There will not be such situation, only lines which have connection point but not crossed.

Comment: IF a wall is connected to up to 2 other walls, this is a binary tree recursion that you have to implement. This is really easy and very well documented on internet.

Comment: @Sebas wall may be connected with more than two wall each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a function on purpose: [getIntersectionList](http://dev.w3.org/SVG/profiles/1.1F2/publish/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__getIntersectionList) that paired with [getBBox](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGLocatable)
could help you to solve your problem. Pseudo code:

```
fillWall(evt) {
 fillConnected(evt.target, [])
}
fillConnected(node, filled) {
 if (!filled.contains(node)) {
   fill(node);
   filled.append(node);
   foreach(n in document.getIntersectionList(node.getBBox()))
    fillConnected(n, filled)
 }
}
```

I'll try to craft actual code using jsFiddle, and will post the address later...

**edit** see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/NBBaF/3/) fiddle, but it seems that Firefox doesnt' still implements the required getIntersectionList. Then if we must craft our own, it's surely best if we cache the lists, because it's going to be a rather costly method...

**edit** I've modified the fiddle' code, that worked just on local files, now in Chrome run fine, but where the walls just touch, the getIntersectionList doesn't work. So we must anyway implement our own version... See you later...

**edit** well, at last the fiddle seems to work. Please note that walls must have their endpoints sorted (x2 >= x1, y2 >= y1), You can see on that walls coloured yellow (corrected) and green (still wrong) the effect of that sort.

Comment: I appreciate that. I think that getIntersectionList is not the best way, though questionable implementation in browsers. I got the best by using x1,y1,x2,y2 attributes.

Comment: That's it. Sorting of endpoints values is the most easiest part. Check your acc.pts please & thanks so much.

Comment: Thank you for the question. I'm learning SVG as well and I find rewarding to help on some basic task.

Comment: Is there any way to send you personal message?

Comment: you can mail me at carlo <at> erboristeriasantanna.it

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo-code version of mine:

```
function doWall(I_oWall) {
    if I_oWall.painted then return;
    I_oWall.paint();
    for each wall in walls
        if I_oWall.isAdjacentTo(wall) then
            doWall(wall);
        end if
    loop
}
```

Sorry, I know it is not a full and complete answer but I think it will really help you in how to figure out your issue.

cheers

Comment: I added vote for your attention, but the problem is more complex ...thx.

Comment: Try to solve it on my example and you'll figure. At least it is complex for me.

Comment: well this is the same, just build your own object model: wall object is actually a line...

Comment: Yes, it is line, I just represent that as wall. Note that line is determined by 2 points, and space in between. It touched other lines in various points or vice versa. I think that function has to change dynamically with recursions.

Comment: implement this logic in the wall.isAdjacentTo function